# neo4j rest api loop structures in prune evaluator

Tags: rest, loops, neo4j, traversal

with the REST api traversal ,
is it possible to put loop structures in the body of the prune_evaluator ?
according to this example : http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-traverse.html#rest-api-traversal-using-a-return-filter

i would like to get a property of all relationships of my path but i dont know how to do with relationships() : 
http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/2.1.0-M02/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html

greeting

Answer (score 0):

If you mean javascript loops, then yes, you can put arbitrary javascript code in the evaluator. As long as the expression returns a boolean value.

Something like

```
var counter=0; for(var i=0;i<10;i++) { counter++; }; counter > 5;
```